# Can't get true/false value from command line in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, namespaces, arguments, argparse

I'm trying to incorporate a flag in to a program:

```
python2.7 hello.py --showxy
```

and `argparse` is giving me trouble.

this is my example test code:

```
import os
import sys
import argparse

print (os.getcwd())
print ("___________________________________________________")
print ("A: " + sys.argv[0])
print ("B: " + sys.argv[1])
print ("C: " + sys.argv[2])
print ("___________________________________________________")


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--showxy', action='store_true')
args = argparse.Namespace()
d = vars(args)


print Namespace()
```

And while I *should* be getting:

```
Namespace(showxy=True)
```

I am *actually* getting an error:

```
A: hello.py
B: haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
C: euromil.jpg
___________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 19, in <module>
    print Namespace()

NameError: name 'Namespace' is not defined
```

How should I be formatting this?

Comment: Why do you think you *should* be getting that? `Namespace` is under `argparse` and you accessed it already as `argparse.Namespace()`. Why do you think calling `Namespace` would work?

Comment: You didn't even call `parser.parse_args()`. Why are you trying to call `Namespace` directly?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the parsing step

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

`args = argparse.Namespace()` just creates an new empty `Namespace` object.

`argparse` is the module.  `parser` is the `ArgumentParser` object.  `Namespace` is a class defined in that module.  `parse_args` creates a `Namespace`, fills it with values that that it parses from `sys.argv`, and returns it as `args`.

Defining the `parser` by itself does not do any parsing.

---

The very first example in the docs is:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

Some claim this is too advanced for beginners, but the key pieces are there.

```
parser = ...
parser.add_argument...
args = parser.parse_args()
# look at args, print it, access attributes, etc.
```

`argparse.Namespace` isn't mentioned until section https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object

Comment: Got it. Is that before or after the namespace?

Comment: You don't normally need to create a `Namespace` yourself.  `parse_args` does that for you. (you can create a Namespace and pass it to the parse_args, but that's advanced usage).   You may need to review the `argparse` docs, and/or tutorial.

Comment: Ok, now I got: `"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse_args'`

Comment: Correction, I should have written `parser.parse_args()`.  `parse_args` is a method of the parser, not a function of the module.  Please go read the docs and try some of the examples.